# Curl. Check redirect

Tags: linux, ubuntu, curl

Lets suppose that we have 3 links: link1, link2, link3. link1 redirects to link2 and link2 redirects to link3. So how to see that with curl?

Comment: There are some good anseres here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074288/get-final-url-after-curl-is-redirected

Answer (score 15):

You can see the HTML headers using `-I`. If the redirect is a meta-refresh it would should up in this way as a header.

```
curl -I http://google.com
```

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.google.com/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Thu, 21 Nov 2013 14:59:13 GMT
Expires: Sat, 21 Dec 2013 14:59:13 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=2592000
Server: gws
Content-Length: 219
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Alternate-Protocol: 80:quic
```

If the redirect is happening via PHP, you could detect this by comparing where the browser is going vs. where it's actually going. There are a bunch of ways to do this with Python, JS, etc.  One project which may be interesting to you is `phantomjs`, a scriptable headless browser.

Answer (score 8):

From `man curl`:

```
   -w, --write-out <format>
          Defines what to display on stdout after a completed and
          successful operation.

          <...>

          redirect_url   When an HTTP request was made without -L to
                         follow redirects, this variable will show the 
                         actual URL a redirect would take you to.
                         (Added in 7.18.2)
```

So probably `curl -w "%{redirect_url}" link1` will give you the first redirection url.

Maybe something like this works for you:

```
URL="http://google.com"
while [ -n "${URL}" ]
do
    echo $URL
    URL=$(curl -sw "\n\n%{redirect_url}" "${URL}" | tail -n 1)
done
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this :

```
for link in link1 link2 link3; do
    curl -Is "$link" | awk '/Location/{print $2}'
done
```

Or using [netcat](/questions/tagged/netcat) :

```
for link in link1 link2 link3; do
    printf '%s\n%s\n\n%s\n' 'HEAD / HTTP/1.1' "Host: $link" 'Connexion:close' |
    netcat $link 80 | awk '/Location/{print $2}'
done
```

Answer (score 3):

Redirects can be checked with `curl -IL`

`curl -IL stackexchange.com`

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
cache-control: private
location: https://stackexchange.com/
...

HTTP/2 200
...
```

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing, on Debian system and macOS, "location" needs to be lowercase and the matching string needs to be more specific to avoid false positives, so the awk solution proposed by @Gilles should be:

```
for link in link1 link2 link3; do
    curl -Is "$link" | awk '/^location/{print $2}'
done
```